# No se puede correr app con flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

He intentado durante todo el día correr una app que he venido terminando desde ayer, (Desde Android Studio y vs code). No sé por qué hoy no ha querido correr repentinamente. (Hasta ayer funcionaba todo a la perfección)

Tanto Vs Code como Android Studio logran correr el proyecto sin problema, pero no se muestra la app en el emulador:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM N975F in debug mode...
Formato de par�metros incorrecto:
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             17,0s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
```

La app logra construirse, pero no se lanza ni se muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 3.4.0-36.0.pre.11, on Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.19044.2006], locale es-CO)
[X] Windows Version (Unable to confirm if installed Windows version is 10 or greater)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.4)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.71.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

He intentado cada uno de las siguientes instrucciones, pero ninguno ha logrado solucionar el problema de correr la app.

- Eliminar carpeta de Android Studio y reinstalar
- Reinstalar Visual Studio Community 2022
- Eliminar carpeta build
- hacer `Flutter channel master`
- hacer `Flutter upgrade`
- hacer `Flutter clean`
- hacer `cd Android` - `.\gradlew clean`
- hacer `flutter run`
- correr la app desde varios emuladores

Aún al hacer lo anterior, el problema persiste:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Solucioné este arduo problema despues de 6 horas buscando solución.

Este es el paso a paso de lo que se debe hacer (deben estar situados en channel master primero):

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter downgrade 1.6.3 or (1.6.6)`
- `flutter channel stable`
- `flutter upgrade`

Luego el editor pedirá hacer `flutter packages get`

y finalmente hacemos `flutter run`.

Pueden correr el proyecto como debug desde el archivo home (opcional).

De nada.